# How to use the mouseClicked()

Tags: java

So If you haven't seen the game SlitherLink, look it up. Anyway, say I have a grid of dots. If I click between 2 dots then it draw a line between the 2 dots just like the SLitherLink game. By question is, I am trying to make it so when you use the mouseClicked method it gets the coordinates of the click and sees which line between 2 dots it should draw. I.e. horizontal or vertical.

This was my mouseClicked() method:

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
for (int i = 0;  i < game.size() + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0;  j < game.size() + 1; j++) {
                if (e.getX() >= i * 100 +10 && e.getX() < i+1 * 100 +10){
                    horizontalClick(i * 100 + 10,j * 100 + 10);
                }
            }

        }
```

This code is saying if the click is between the first dot and the second dot in the loop, draw the horizontal line. I know this is wrong but this is what I have tried.

```
public void horizontalClick(int r, int c)
    {
        if ((r >= 0 && r < game.size()) && c >= 0 && c < game.size()) {
            sc.drawLine(r, c, r+1, c, Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

I am using the SimpleCanvas Class to draw on a window.

So basically, since the click is never precise how can I say where the mouse is clicked find the nearest dot and see whether it should be a vertical or horizontal line from that dot.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rounding to the nearest relevant point?

Comment: @DavisHerring Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Like `(x+2)/5*5` rounds a non-negative integer to the nearest multiple of 5?